# Jenkins Plugin debug "Dependency ui-samples-plugin (1.509) doesn't exist"

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I ran into this problem debugging a Jenkins plugin with Eclipse and I wanted to post the solution here so that when people googled it, they could get a good answer.
I added:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-samples-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.509</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To my paren pom and I was able to build and debug. I just wanted to let people know, because I couldn't find anything after a couple hours of searching.

Answer (score 1):

http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog

> What's new in 1.535 (2013/10/14)
>   UI Samples plugin fully separated from core. To view samples during
>   plugin development or at any other time, just install from the update
>   center.

During plugin development, you may want to lock your Jenkins version to the an older version so you don't end up in latest and greatest hell, LTS is 1.509.

Do you have the proper parent definition?

Here is an example from the artifactory plugin pom that defines the Jenkins version to lock to (They lock against 1.428):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.428</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thanks. We're on LTS 1.509, and the plugin was built against that version, still got the problem. I don't really know what's causing it, but the solution seemed easy enough after I did it.